# Connect a raspberry with samba

Tags: raspberry-pi3, samba, smb

[image: Screenshot of options in the folder.]

In the image above you see "Type: SSH" in the Remove Server options.
There are other options for Type available like FTP and WebDAV but I need samba to connect to the server in my work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the `samba` packages? Try:

`sudo apt install  samba-common smbclient samba-common-bin smbclient cifs-utils`

Then (maybe reboot) and see if there's a samba option available. If the option isn't available, then that software may just not support Samba shares, in which case see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40974/access-network-samba-share-from-pi-client), for a command line version.

Note: Just like that post, this question belongs on the [dedicated Raspberry Pi stack exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).